# How can I make a Text View change it's position based on what the user puts in the Text View above?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple layout filled with 4 `TextView`'s, 2 of which are pre-filled with text, as number 1 and 3 from top. The two other are filled in based on witch `ListItem` the user taps. They are filled with different lengths of text, so the majority of times, the texts overlap.

How can I make number 3 and 4 position themselves further down on the screen, if the texts overlap?

Code is attached below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bildeAvGjenstand"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bildeBesk"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THIS IS PREFILLED"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""                      
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bildeAvGjenstand"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjoremaal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text=""   <!-- I want this text view to change position -->
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  <!-- I want this text view to change position -->
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="THIS IS PREFILLED"
    android:textSize="35sp" />
```

Comment: By overlap, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the text that is filled in when the user taps a certain list item goes over the prefilled text, so the text gets unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the structure is a little weird. I'm not sure what the end goal of what your trying to do is but I think i have an idea. I rewrote the code here for you that will adjust the items below based on the size of the text above.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="THIS IS PREFILLED"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjoremaal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="This text changes "
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THIS IS PREFILLED"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gjoremaal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This text changes"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bildeAvGjenstand"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="sample"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think what he's going for would be dynamic.